# Laravel Eloquent many to many relationship with different column as key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following models

```
Category
    id           // we don't want to use this one for the relation
    category_id  // we want to use this

Product
    id

CategoryProduct
    product_id  // points to "id" on products table
    category_id // points to **category_id** on categories table
```

I have the Product model set up as follows (only the most recent variation).

```
class Product {
    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'categories_products', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

When I try to get a product with categories as follows...

```
Product::with('categories')->get();
```

I either get the wrong categories because the query is using `id` on `categories` as the foreign key. I need it to be using `category_id` on the categories table.

Or I get none at all. I can't seem to hash out how to set up which columns to use on the `belongsToMany` method.

Comment: I think you want `hasManyThrough` see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: The [Many To Many documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) has a good example what goes in each argument position for `belongsToMany()`. Try `return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'categories_products', 'product_id', 'category_id');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this follow,

```
    class Product {
          public function categories() {
              return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'categories_products', 'product_id','category_id');
          }
    }
```